# Is it possible to create class using JSON schema in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I want to create class from JSON schema using JAVA API.
 And later I want to insert JSONs. Is it possible?

**Use case is**: 
I want to store Person, Person-profile(JSON) as vertices and create edge between the same. 
Also I would like to query over JSON fields and retrieve Person and traverse related vertices etc.
Correct me if this is wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. 
See http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-Java.html for some examples. 
If you have specific questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Sorry I am not able locate Class creation using JSON Schema, please point it out